# Why does NMF (Non Negative Matrix Factorization) decompose a spectrogram into time and frequency component?

Tags: stft, decomposition, matrix-factorization

I compute the NMF over a spectrogram (magnitude of STFT of a signal) in this way:

```
W,H = NMF(MyStft,r) # where r=2 is the rank
```

**W** and **H** respectively  contain  the  spectrum  and  the  temporal information.

My question is why? What's the logic behind that?

Comment: Imagine that you are trying to separate some chords from a piano recording. Assuming you set your NMF parameters correctly, ideally, you will end up with a decomposition where $W$ will contain each chord and $H$ will tell the time activations for these chords. Alternatively, you could learn separate decompositions for each instrument, save the $W$ matrix for each instrument, stack those matrices together and perform decomposition on a recording which contains those instruments, while freezing the $W$ matrix. You can separate instruments now thanks to disjoint time-frequency representation.

Comment: @jojek following this explanation, since the original matrix X had n columns, and im making a rank 2 decomposition, you would agree that the cords are no long the same in the W matrix. So if W is a m x 2 matrix it means i have exactly 2 columns. what are those columns. what do they represent in regards to the original signal.

Comment: They will represent some optimal combination of frequencies which minimizes the loss function for your decomposition. In theory, if you set rank to be equal to the number of chords, you *might* get one chord per column as their frequency content. In case of rank is very low (like 2 in your case), the factorization will be just approximate. Each column of $W$ will be some _spectrum_, which is added together and multiplied by time activations to approximate the input spectrogram.

Comment: [This might be an example](http://d-kitamura.net/demo/defNMF/nmf_en.png).
In general, rank is important.

Comment: Is it true that NMF tends to find a certain «structure» by factoring into the product of two smaller matrixes? That (say) a saxophone playing a tune tends to have repeated timbre that is «trigged» like a sampler (only more variability), and NMF is one method that tends to approximate this structure well (for some definition of «well»)?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to DSP SE!

A [Spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) is a **time-frequency representation**: a representation of the spectrum of **frequencies** of a signal as it varies with **time**.
You can think of it as a **non-negative** (when you take the absolute value as you mentioned) 2D matrix (think columns = time, rows = frequencies, with each entry in the matrix containing the amplitude of a particular frequency component at a particular time instant).

[NMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization) is a group of algorithms that aims at expressing a **non-negative** matrix $X$ as a **factor** of 2 **non-negative matrices** $W$ and $H$. In our case, NMF tries to *separate* the time-frequency information contained in our Spectrogram $X$ into 2 matrices: one for **frequency**, one for **time**:

- $X$ is the spectrogram magnitude, so it can be factorized into
- $W$, a set of basis spectral vectors, and
- $H$, a set of temporal activation weights.

I know these terms can be quite confusing. **May I suggest you study this great tutorial: [Bill Connelly - Nonnegative Matrix Factorization for Dummies](http://www.billconnelly.net/?p=534)**? If you still have questions (maybe a little more precise than the one you asked), feel free to edit or add to your original question ;)

Comment: Yes i get this part. and it seems this is what all the papers and articles are saying. but my question is what is W. if W is now some m by nComponents. what its  relationship with the origianal signal. are the columns of W also signals? because im not getting this idea of basis or spectral signatures.

Comment: Have you gone through the tutorial I linked?

Comment: In this context "basis" is a word for the collection of individual parts something is made up of. If NMF is applied to faces, for example, the basis "vectors" (which can be visualized as matrices) may look like this: https://www.spsc.tugraz.at/collections/assets/NMFFaces.png.

Comment: @Jdip, I think the question is the other way around. You explain why it is reasonable to get such decomposition while I think the question is, among so many options, why does this decomposition is chosen? How come that indeed the matrix in the result matches the time and frequency. This has more to do with the efficiency of the representation.